# Get Firebase makeDocumentSnapshot to work

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) Firebase guide to setup my tests. Everything OK except for the "constructing data" part.

I'm wondering if `test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({foo: 'bar'}, 'collection/doc')` is supposed to actually create a document in the online Firestore or it just returns the `DocumentSnapshot` object?.

I've tried it and it doesn't create a thing, I suppose my rules are fine cause I'm able to read other docs under same path inside the Function under test. Does that my that I need to create my test data like?:

```
const store = admin.firestore();
store.doc("collection/doc").set({ id: "123" });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All it does is create a DocumentSnapshot object.  As shown in the documentation you linked, you would use it to simulate the documents that would get delivered to an invocation of a Firestore trigger that expects snapshots.

Comment: thanks doug, so that means if I wanna test a Function that reads data from Firestore, I need to persist data as I showed, then test, then cleanup?...

Comment: Yes, you will need to stage the contents of the database before testing.